# Magento 2 get tax class id by product in website scope

Tags: magento2.3, php, tax-class

I have a product that belongs to `All store views` and `India website`
and the config for tax class in `All store views` is different from `India website`

And I'm using `$product->getTaxClassId()` so it only can get tax id for the default website  (`All store views`)

How I can get a tax class id for this product with the website `India website` on the backend side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this code :

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$resource = $product->getResource();
$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();

$resource->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE',$store->getId());
```